# How-To: Access local minikube cluster, with kubectl running inside VSCode Development Container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, docker-desktop

I have minikube cluster running on Windows WSL2, and I have a Dev Container https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container) running my React Application and Kubernetes CLI tools. My goal is to containerize the application and run that on the minikube cluster.

So now I have exposed the local configurations and certifications of minikube to my Dev Container, and I am using that as a default KUBECONFIG. I have a deployment, and Docker Image ready - so next step is to try to use deployment and have that running on the cluster.

When I am running a kubectl command inside the Dev Container, I am getting error message like this:

```
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:51515 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

When I am inspecting the minikube container, I see that its listening only to localhost

```
gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28                          "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 hours ago          Up 3 hours          127.0.0.1:58892->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:58893->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:58895->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:58896->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:58894->32443/tcp   minikube
```

So as far as I know, these requests fail, because request from Dev Container is not considered as a localhost request (I am able to ping localhost.). I am running the Dev Container with network=host flag.

So atleast one way to get this setup working it to bind minikube's ports to listen to 0.0.0.0, instead of localhost - is there any other way? How could I get that 0.0.0.0 bind working? I am having a feeling that this could be Docker Desktop settings related - that I need to somehow change some kind of default settings from 127.0.0.1 -> 0.0.0.0.

Running minikube with this command didn't do the trick.

```
minikube start --driver=docker --listen-address='0.0.0.0'
```

Versions:

- Docker Desktop 4.6.0 (75818)
- Docker 20.10.13, build a224086
- minikube v1.24.0
- kubectl 1.21.5

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I also tried different alternatives to localhost, without changing the configuration in minikube, with the same port that is on host computer - these didn't do the trick. I can however ping every address from Container.

```
kubernetes.docker.internal, host.docker.internal, 192.168.49.2 (Minikube's IP on localhost), minikubeCA, control-plane.minikube.internal, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default, kubernetes, localhost
```

Here is my minikube's KUBECONFIG.

```
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: Removed for Security.
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Mon, 28 Mar 2022 17:30:48 EEST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.24.0
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://localhost:58896
  name: minikube
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. Docker Desktop requires to use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` inside Kubernetes Config YAML.

Problem is that first address is not allowed by Minikubes Certificate. Running kubectl commands with flag `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` - so for example

```
kubectl get nodes -A --insecure-skip-tls-verify
```

works, with setup defined above.

Found also some documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/kubernetes-helm

Comment: You also can start the minikube cluster with `--apiserver-names="host.docker.internal"` so the certificates also include that address